# How to remove magnet paint from regular drywall?

Tags: drywall, repainting, paint-removal

Previous owner painted a 3 ft. by 4 ft. rectangle with magnet paint on kitchen wall. He/she used very heavy strokes. Paint is thick, has ugly, thick lines and bubbles all over.

I've been unsuccessfully trying to remove this thing so I can repaint the kitchen.
First, I tried scraping with a [paint scraper](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Blue-Hawk-4-Pack-Steel-Paint-Scrapers-Common-3-5-in-Actual-3-5-in/50094768)... it didn't do anything.
Then tried sanding with coarse sandpaper... applied heavy pressure for about one hour until my arms got tired and nothing. All it did was smooth out the thick brush lines and bubbles a bit.

If I could sand it down to a smooth look, I could apply primer then paint, but even after one hour of vigorous sanding, I cannot remove or smooth the magnet paint enough.

Comment: have you tried regular paint stripper?

Comment: That stuff is supposed to go on thick so there is enough metal mass to grab.  I mean it's 100sf/gallon by spec.  By contrast the LPU I use is 1000sf/gal.   Don't hand sand anymore, vibratory sanders are cheap.

Comment: @aaron - No. I'm afraid paint stripper wouldn't work since this is not a regular latex or oil-based paint. Also afraid the paint stripper would damage the drywall/floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Locate the studs on either side of the area affected.
- Cut down the middle of the studs, and horizontally above and below
  the affected area.
- Remove drywall and bad paint.
- Insert new drywall
- Mud/feather/etc as per usual for patching
- Paint.

Comment: HaHa. Right. That's what I'm afraid I'm going to have to do. Hopefully someone will have an idea of how to remove that paint. If not, will resort to this. Thanks : )

Comment: Not a joke - drywall repair is often faster/easier than fighting a terrible coating stuck to drywall.